# How to move the entire background inversely to the cursor of mouse pointer p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to make my background moving against where my mouse cursor is, just like this.

[image]

As the mouse cursor located upper left, the background picture should go to downward right.

[image]

As the mouse cursor located upper right, the background picture should go to downward left.

[image]

As the mouse cursor located left, the background picture should go to right.

The background photo should be infinite and can fill the entire canvas with an x and y sizes. How can i do this with p5.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Break your problem down into smaller steps.](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program)

**Step 1:** First just get a rectangle moving with the mouse position. Get that working perfectly before moving to the next step.

**Step 2:** Then get the rectangle moving **inversely** to the mouse position. Think about how you'd do this by drawing some examples on a piece of graph paper. What is the mouse position? What should the rectangle's position be? Repeat this until you notice a pattern.

**Step 3:** Now that you have a single rectangle moving inversely to the mouse position, get a grid of rectangles to do the same thing. For loops are your friend here, and you might have to do something clever with moving rectangles from one side to the other if you want it to be infinite.

**Step 4:** Now just use an image instead of rectangles.

If you get stuck on a specific step, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing **just that step** and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Wow amazing. You make me think always and I always figure out what to do next. Haha. Thank you Mr. Workman, i use **loadImage()** and use a nested **for** loop for the x and y position of the image and use an **if** statement for the **modulo** condition. Thank you Mr. Workman :)

Comment: However, I'm thinking if this will cause the program to make slower because of so many for loops with large range? Because i start from -1800 to 1800 both x and y. Watcha think?

Comment: I used also **translate()** so I could move the image inversely.

Comment: @JoshuaAlzate I can't really tell you whether your code will be slow. But if you don't notice any slowdown I wouldn't worry too much about it.